# How to change an out link to an in link in doors

Tags: ibm-doors

In doors, I have a few links that are wrongly directed,that is the links are out links but I would like to make them in links. Can someone help me out with a dxl script that could do this easily. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick script to change the direction of the link on all out-links in the current object.

Assumptions:

1) Both source and target modules are open in exclusive edit.

2) You want all links out of the current object to be changed to in-links.

3) Creating links through DXL ignores your current Linkset restrictions.

```
Object o = current
Object t
Link l, l2
string LinkMod = "NAME_OF_YOUR_LINK_MODULE_HERE"

for l in o -> "*" do
{
    t = target(l)
    t -> LinkMod -> o
    delete l
}
flushDeletions
```

You can easily edit this script to open the modules you want or to only update specific links if you have more information about what you want to update, but it should get you started.

Good Luck